# Perforce p4 on high sierra doesnt respond

Tags: perforce

After updating to High Sierra my p4 client no longer responds. I've tried removing uninstall (via brew) and reinstalling it and nothing seems to work. It seems to find the reference to p4 however the terminal just takes the command and does nothing. It Just moves to a newline. Anyone have any ideas on how to resolve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the `p4` binary you have is the p4 command line client and not some other tool with the same executable name?

Does `p4 -V` print the version information?

Is it possible that there's a password prompt somewhere on the desktop asking you for authorization to run this unapproved executable?

Comment: im sure there is no other p4 binary on my system. p4 -V brings me into some console which accepts no commands that I can think of. no password prompts are anywhere on any of the desktops. For now i've just installed the perforce UI and its working. I'll leave this open awhile incase someone has an answer.

Comment: `p4 -V` should just display version information and exit.  Whatever `p4` binary you have is not the Perforce client (or is not a valid executable for your platform).    (Re)installing `p4` should fix it.